# Average arc length between two random points on a unit sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, surfaces

I'm trying to find the average arc length between two random points on a unit sphere. The solution I've come up with is rather ugly. Consider a parametric surface:

$$X(u,v)=\sin u\cos v\\Y(u,v)=\cos u\cos v\\Z(u,v)=\sin v$$

(For a sphere, $u\in[0,2\pi]$, $v\in\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$). Then, integrate the distance formula for two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2)$along all three axes. This turns into a nasty integral, though.

$$F(\ldots)=\int_0^{2\pi}
    \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
        D(X_1,Y_1,Z_1,X_2,Y_2,Z_2)dv\mbox{ }du$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}F(\ldots)\mbox{ }dv\mbox{ }du$$

(Where $D(\ldots)$ is the arc length formula.) I could plug this into mathematica or something, but I have a feeling this would

- take too long to compute
- be too complex
- probably also be wrong

What is a more efficient way to do this? How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the average arc length or the average distance? Your formula appears to be a distance formula.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to have your first point fixed at $(0,0,r)$?

Comment: @Lord Ah, yeah, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: @steve No, since the probability (afaik) should be different if both points may be moved. Correct me if I'm wrong, though; this is an assumption I'm making.

Comment: I agree with @stevemarvell. I guess that the solution is $\pi$. (with $r=1$)

Comment: @Emrakul You could always rotate the co-ordinate system to make the first random point the origin.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'd assume that was the maximum.

Comment: @steve That is a very good idea, thanks! I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Emrakul I meant as an assumption as to why you can do it from an origin point. I'm going to guess it's $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for "shortest distance" and $\pi$ for long and short ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the coordinates so the first point is at the pole and measure $\theta$ from $0$ at that pole to $\pi$ at the other one.  The distance to the other point is then $\theta$.  The probability distribution of $\theta$ is proportional to $\sin \theta$ as that is the radius of the small circle the second point is on.  Your average distance is then 
$$\frac {\int_0^\pi \theta \sin(\theta) d\theta}{\int_0^\pi \sin(\theta) d\theta}=\frac {\pi}{2}$$
We can see this is true by matching up points at $\theta$ with points at $\pi - \theta$  The average of each pair is $\frac \pi 2$

Answer (score 1):

For a sphere with unitary radius we have

[image: Arc_medio_sfera]

The "number" of points having the arc-distance $\alpha$ is measured by the area of the annulus
$\sin \alpha d\alpha$, so

$$
\begin{gathered}
  \overline \alpha   = \frac{1}
{{\underbrace {4\pi }_{\text{tot}\text{.}\,\text{weight}}}}\int_{\alpha  = 0}^{\,\pi } {\overbrace \alpha ^{\text{value}}\,\overbrace {2\pi \sin \alpha d\alpha }^{\text{weight}}\,}  = \frac{1}
{2}\int_{\alpha  = 0}^{\,\pi } {\alpha \,\sin \alpha d\alpha \,}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\left. { - \alpha \,\cos \alpha } \right|_{\alpha  = 0}^{\,\pi }  - \int_{\alpha  = 0}^{\,\pi } {\cos \alpha d\alpha \,} } \right) = \frac{\pi }
{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

which shall be expected, given the symmetry of the *Northern* and *Southern* emisphere.

Comment: How on Earth... was this question linked somewhere?

Comment: @Emrakul: sorry, do not understand what you mean to ask.

Comment: I mean to say, I asked this question in October 2013. I'm _really_ curious how you found it?

Comment: @Emrakul: ah, that's true .. it's quite an old post !! actually I was thinking it was quite "fresh" instead: I don't remember exactly, but it should have popped out among the **active** questions .. (?!)